Fourier analysis for determining behaviour of error in solving difference equation
Suppose that $e_n^m$ are the finite-precision errors introduced into the solution of
\begin{equation}
u_n^{m+1}=\alpha u_{n+1}^{m}+(1-2\alpha) u_n^m+\alpha u_{n-1}^m
\end{equation}
because of initial rounding errors, $e_n^0$, in the exact initial values when represented on a computer. Why do the $e_n^m$ also satisfy that equation? As a consequence of Fourier analysis, we may assume (without any loss of generality) that the errors take the form $e_n^m = \lambda^m \sin(n\omega)$ for some given frequency $\omega$.
This is part of exercise from book "The mathematics for Financial Derivatives". It is easy to see that $e_n^m$ satisfy same condition as $u_n^m$, but I don't understand how did they get  part $e_n^m = \lambda^m \sin(n\omega)$? What exactly did they do?

This is the diffusion equation, right? Shouldn't the first term in your finite difference equation be $\alpha u_{n+1}^m$ instead of $\alpha u_n^m$?

@JohnBarber   You are right, edited now...

I suspect what they're saying is that $e_n^m$ can be decomposed into a sum of modes of various frequencies $\omega$, and that for a given mode we have $e_n^m(\omega) = \lambda^m(\omega) \sin(n\omega)$. Note that if we substitute this expression for $e_n^m(\omega)$ into your difference relation, we get $\lambda(\omega) = 1 - 4\alpha\sin^2(\omega/2)$. This dispersion relation tells you how fast the different spatial modes in the error will grow (or shrink) with time.
